# How to get current road(street) name in HERE SDK Navigate Edition (4.13.2.0)

Tags: android, navigation, maps, here-api

I've got `com.here.sdk.routing.Route`, `VisualNavigator`, `RouteProgressListener` (and other listeners) and started navigation.
I recieve necessary  `RouteProgress` in `onRouteProgressUpdated`.

```
Route?.sections?.forEach {
    it.maneuvers.forEach {
        it?.roadTexts?.names?.defaultValue   // here is null very often
    }
}
```

```
routeProgress.maneuverProgress.forEach {
            val maneuver = it?.maneuverIndex?.let { it1 -> VisualNavigator.getManeuver(it1) }
            maneur?.roadTexts?.names?.defaultValue   //here is null all the time
        }
```

How can i get current road(street) name (right way)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the road name like this -

```
private fun getRoadName(maneuver: Maneuver): String? {
        val currentRoadTexts = maneuver.roadTexts
        val nextRoadTexts = maneuver.nextRoadTexts
        val currentRoadName = currentRoadTexts.names.defaultValue
        val currentRoadNumber = currentRoadTexts.numbers.defaultValue
        val nextRoadName = nextRoadTexts.names.defaultValue
        val nextRoadNumber = nextRoadTexts.numbers.defaultValue
        var roadName = nextRoadName ?: nextRoadNumber

        // On highways, we want to show the highway number instead of a possible road name,
        // while for inner city and urban areas road names are preferred over road numbers.
        if (maneuver.nextRoadType == RoadType.HIGHWAY) {
            roadName = nextRoadNumber ?: nextRoadName
        }
        if (maneuver.action == ManeuverAction.ARRIVE) {
            // We are approaching the destination, so there's no next road.
            roadName = currentRoadName ?: currentRoadNumber
        }
        if (roadName == null) {
            // Happens only in rare cases, when also the fallback is null.
            roadName = "unnamed road"
        }
        return roadName
    }
```

I hope this answers your query.